# How to escape ANSI format on remote SSH command?

Tags: ssh

I wanted to change the title of the window using the command as described [here](https://www.networkinghowtos.com/howto/how-to-set-the-putty-window-title-via-script/) over SSH, however I kept get getting the error:

```
033]sh: Hello: command not found
Connection to host closed.
```

with the command:

```
ssh.exe user@host -t 'echo -en "\033];Hello World\007"'
```

No matter how I try to escape them, it seems to somehow return error. Tried:

```
ssh.exe user@host -t 'echo -en "\\033];Hello World\\007"'
ssh.exe user@host -t "echo -en \'\\033];Hello World\\007\'"
```

Any idea how to fix this?